# Nextjs 13.2.1 - UnhandledRejection error in Next.js project: "TypeError: trace.getSpan is not a function"

Tags: next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project and I keep getting an UnhandledRejection error with the following message:

TypeError: trace.getSpan is not a function

I've searched for solutions online but couldn't find anything that works. Here's what I've tried so far:

Upgrading to the latest version of Next.js (currently 13.2.1).
Reinstalling Node.js, npm, and yarn to make sure they're up to date.
Checking my VS Code settings to see if anything could be causing the error.
None of these steps have solved the issue. Any help or guidance on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIUtt.jpg)

- Reinstalling Node.js, npm, and yarn to make sure they're up to date.
- Checking my VS Code settings to see if anything could be causing the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnpJA.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by installing @opentelemetry as described at https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/instrumentation/

```
npm install \
  @opentelemetry/api \
  @opentelemetry/resources \
  @opentelemetry/semantic-conventions \
  @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node \
  @opentelemetry/instrumentation
```